# In Chrome console: What is "detected mammaliaforme"?

Tags: google-chrome, console.log

I've Googled this and nothing comes up. So this is some new DOM warning that I have discovered completely on my own. WTH is this?...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be related to a recent LastPass update, although that's as much as I know.

Comment: Wow, how did you find out it's LastPass? I sure do have that installed in Chrome right now.

Comment: A coworker was getting the same error and I came across a [LastPass forum thread](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5K1cZ9698U8J:https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D14%26t%3D178115+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) that mentioned this console output. Turns out my coworker had LastPass installed, too, and he noticed it had updated recently.

Comment: @Locohost in the devtools you can see the filename that outputted that log line. if you follow the file, you will notice that a chrome extension loaded it. if you copy the id and google it, you will go to the chrome extensions page of lastpass

Answer (score 1):

If you check in dev tools you'll see that the warning is related to 'onloadwff.js'. If you click on that file reference and hover the tab for that file in the sources panel you'll see that the tooltip shows it is part of a chrome extension. I can confirm that disabling the LastPass extension resolves the warning.